# python OpenCV jpeg compression in memory

Tags: python, opencv, jpeg

In OpenCV it is possible to save an image to disk with a certain jpeg compression. Is there also a way to do this in memory? Or should I write a function using `cv2.imsave()` that loads the file and removes it again from disk? If anyone knows a better way that is also fine.

The use case is real-time data augmentation. Using something else than OpenCV would cause possibly unnecessary overhead.

Example of desired function `im = cv2.imjpgcompress(90)`

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You can use `imencode`:

```
encode_param = [int(cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY), 90]
result, encimg = cv2.imencode('.jpg', img, encode_param)
```

(The default value for [`IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY`](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga292d81be8d76901bff7988d18d2b42ac) is 95.)

You can decode it back with:

```
decimg = cv2.imdecode(encimg, 1)
```

---

<sub>Snippet from [here](https://github.com/kyatou/python-opencv_tutorial/blob/master/08_image_encode_decode.py)</sub>

Comment: The shape of the encimg is different from that of im. Why is that? 

Before: 340 1080 3
After: 58154 1

Comment: import cv2

filename = 'image.png'
im = cv2.imread(filename)
encode_param = [int(cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY), 80]
result, im = cv2.imencode('.jpg', im, encode_param)

print result