# Reading An Image And Saving It, Increases the Image Size

Tags: opencv, image-processing, scipy, imread

I've loaded an image using CV2.imread, and saved it using cv2.imwrite() and scipy.misc.imsave(). In both these cases output image size is bumped. Why is this?

Both input and output images are of file type .jpg

```
img = cv2.imread(img_src)
scipy.misc.imsave(img, "scipy_original.jpg")
cv2.imwrite("cv2_original.jpg", img)
```

Input file size is 309kb
Output file size in cv2 is 690kb
output file size in scipy is 399kb

this is the image if you want reference: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qMe0.jpg

Comment: It is using it's default values if we don't specify anything.
refer: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html

Answer (score 3):

OpenCV has different compression levels for jpg, from 0 to 100. The default is 95.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40768621/python-opencv-jpeg-compression-in-memory) question discusses it, and [this](https://www.life2coding.com/save-opencv-images-jpeg-quality-png-compression/) site has examples.

Saving with parameters like this: 
`cv2.imwrite("cv2_original.jpg", img, [int(cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY), jpg_quality])` where `jpg_quality < 95` will reduce the file size.

Comment: But isn't that going to change the quality of the output image? And how does compression affect the image size, I thought using different bit-rates like 8-bit, 16-bit are the causes for increasing in size. Please clarify this point.

Comment: Yes it will change the output quality. Generally more compression == less size == less quality.

Comment: Bit rates also contribute to size, but the compression algorithm and compression level contribute too. I think they make more of a difference than bitrates but I'm not sure about that

Comment: @Beeti: An 8-bit image doesn’t have a bit rate of 8 in a JPEG file. Compression causes the bit rate to drop, for example you can get 0.5 bits per pixel. The compression quality dictates this. The lower the quality, the more data gets lost and the lower the bit rate will be. In a 16-bit image you start off with more bits per pixel, but you can still go down to a very low bit rate. In your case, the input JPEG has a lower quality than the output JPEG, and hence a lower bit rate.

Comment: @CrisLuengo That makes sense, so openCV and scipy by default save the image with higher bit rate while encoding? Can we know the bit rate of an image by any means? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I'm currently using this formula to calculate bit rate or bpp (bits per pixel) =>  (image file size in bits) / (image height pixels * image width pixels * no of channels). But the results come out to be less than 1, it doesn't make sense. Aren't bitrate supposed to be 4-bit 8-bit 16-bit?

Comment: @Beeti: You're calculating bits per sample (rather than bits per pixel, but that's OK too). As I said, bit rates are much less than 8 or 16 in a JPEG image. If you compress the data to 10% of its size, an 8-bit per sample image comes out at 0.8 bits per sample after compression. In memory you have 8 bits per sample, but on file you have only 0.8 bits per sample. This is the whole point of compressing the image.