# Python base64 in HTML - broken image

Tags: python, html, image, base64

I try to do:

- take screenshot using python-mss
- resize and then convert to base64
- using JS load by ajax using python-flask request handler and paste the result to src attribute in img tag like `data:image/png;base64,{{base64}}`

HTML result:
[image]

**get_base64_screenshot.py**

```py
import mss, cv2, base64
import numpy as np

MSS = mss.mss()

# screenshot
frame_bytes = MSS.grab(MSS.monitors[2])

# BGRA -> RGB
frame_array = np.array(frame_bytes)
frame_array = np.flip(frame_array[:, :, :3], 2)

# resize
frame_resized = cv2.resize(frame_array, (640, 360), interpolation = cv2.INTER_CUBIC)

# base64
frame_base64 = base64.b64encode(frame_resized)
```

What am I doing wrong? I think it's wrong decoding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are encoding the raw cv2 image data as base64, which your web browser won't understand. You need to encode the raw image data to jpg and then encode it.

```py
# resize
frame_resized = cv2.resize(frame_array, (640, 360), interpolation = cv2.INTER_CUBIC)

encode_param = [int(cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY), 90]
result, frame_encoded = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame_resized, encode_param)

# base64
frame_base64 = base64.b64encode(frame_encoded)
```

code snippet taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40768621/python-opencv-jpeg-compression-in-memory)