# Opencv imread jpg and change quality

Tags: python, opencv

Is there any function where I can change the quality of a JPG image without saving it first?

```
img = cv2.imread('image.jpg') 
cv2.imwrite('image_high.jpg', img, [int(cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY), 100])
img_high = cv2.imread('image_high.jpg')
```

Edit:
I edited the word 'increase' to 'change'.

Comment: what do you mean by '_increase_ the quality' ? by using `IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY` you want to _decrease_ its quality to get smaller output file size. if that's not what you want, simply use `cv2.imwrite('image_high.jpg', img)` to keep the original quality.

Comment: The size has become larger when I imwrited it with 100 quality. OK, let say I want to decrease/increase the quality while reading it. I don't want to save anything, I just want to process the image with the decreased/increased quality.

Comment: if you want to work with a quality-decreased image, take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40768621/python-opencv-jpeg-compression-in-memory)

Comment: Here is good tutorial [ink]https://machinelearningknowledge.ai/tips-and-tricks-of-opencv-cv2-imwrite-that-nobody-told-you/

Comment: You should remove this [int(

Comment: During reading you will always read the whole quality that the image was saved with. You can't increase/decrease the quality during reading. However you could 1.. save full quality as png 2. cv2.imread 3. cv2.encode (with desired/decreased quality) 3. cv2.decode

Comment: So I no matter what I still need to save it and read it again, am I right? Actually I encountered a very strange issue where I couldn't detect any text using tesseract after reading it (a jpeg file) but when I save it and read it again, I can detect texts.

Comment: @AcaNg That's the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Because JPEG uses lossy compression, when color components (Cb, Cr) are decimated, and all the components (Y, Cb, Cr) have losses also at the DCT, quantization stages - **you can't** just "increase the quality" of the compressed image, because some information (moslty high-frequency and color) is already lost.

You can take a look at this [great paper](https://www.ijg.org/files/Wallace.JPEG.pdf) for further information about JPEG techniques.

By the way, there is lossless [variation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossless_JPEG) of JPEG.

Comment: Very useful info.